# Expected a value of type 'int', but got one of type list<Map<string, dynamic>>

Tags: flutter, dart

i tried to show a listview.builder as child of expanded but had a this message in chrome
"Expected a value of type 'int', but got one of type list<Map<string, dynamic>>" in Flutter

Comment: Please [edit] your question to contain the relevant code as a [mcve] so we can help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of itemCount that your are applying?

```
  itemCount: entries.length
```

Maybe you had put a wrong variable type here.

Try to use int like `list.length`